Minimal and overcomplete exponential families
I am studying Kevin Murphy's Probabilistic Machine Learning: Advanced Topics, version of June 26, 2024. Right now, I am having trouble with some concepts about exponential families.
Definition
Consider a family of probability distributions parameterized by $\mathbf{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ with fixed support over $\mathcal{X}^D ⊆ \mathbb{R}^D$. We say that the distribution $p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{\eta})$ is in the exponential family if its density can be written in the following way:
$$
p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{\eta}) = h(\mathbf{x})\exp\left[\mathbf{\eta}^\intercal\mathcal{T}(\mathbf{x}) - A(\mathbf{\eta})\right]
$$
...
Formally, we say that an exponential family is minimal if there is no $\mathbf{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^k \setminus \\{ 0 \\} $ such that $\mathbf{\eta}^\intercal\mathcal{T}(\mathbf{x}) = 0$.
...
And then, the book gives an example of the Bernoulli distribution.
Bernoulli
The Bernoulli distribution can be written in exponential family form as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Ber}(x|\mu) &= \mu^x(1-\mu)^{1-x} \\\ &= \exp[x \log(\mu) + (1 − x) \log(1 − \mu)] \\\ &= \exp[\mathcal{T}(x)^\intercal\mathbf{\eta}]
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathcal{T}(x) = [\mathbb{I}(x=1),\mathbb{I}(x=0)]$ and $\mathbf{\eta} = [\log(\mu),\log(1-\mu)]$. However, this is an over-complete representation since there is a linear dependence between the features. We can see this as follows:
$$
\mathbf{1}^\intercal\mathcal{T}(x) = \mathbb{I}(x=1) + \mathbb{I}(x=0) = 1
$$
Then, the book continues. If the representation is overcomplete, $\mathbf{\eta}$ is not uniquely identifiable. It is common to use a minimal representation, which means there is a unique $\mathbf{\eta}$ associated with the distribution.
Questions
In the Bernoulli case, why are the features $\mathcal{T}(x)$ linearly dependent?
Is there an example of $\mathbf{\eta}$ where their representation is not unique?
Why it is important to have unique $\mathbf{\eta}$ associated with the distribution.

If you write $\mathcal{T}(x)=(T_1(x),T_2(x))$, then $T_1(x)+T_2(x)=1$ for all possible values of $x$. This is clearly a linear dependence relation.

Since $\eta_1 T_1(x)+\eta_2T_2(x)=\eta_1 T_1(x)+\eta_2(1-T_1(x))$, one can change the value of $\mathbf \eta$ under the constraint that $\eta_1-\eta_2$ is constant without changing the density of $X$.
